# Community Toolkit MVVM doesn't bind data between View and View Model, using WPF .NET framework 4.8

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, windows-community-toolkit

My ViewModel

```
partial class TestViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        private string inputText;
    }
```

My View

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp_framework.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp_framework"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
        xmlns:viewModel ="clr-namespace:WpfApp_framework.ViewModel">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <viewModel:TestViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=InputText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=InputText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Data doesn't bind. how to resolve this?

- Community Toolkit MVVM 8.1
- WPF .NET Framework 4.8

But it works when I use .NET 6 or 7. How can I make MVVM Toolkit work on .NET Framework 4.8?

Comment: Look at the dependencies list for the nuget package. See where it says Net standard 2.0 and 2.1?  Those are net core which was invented after net 4.8.   The partial classes generation relies on source generators which are a relatively new thing. I'm not sure they even work in vs2019.

Comment: Perhaps you noticed [MVVMTK0008](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/generators/errors/mvvmtk0008) error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click on the `packages.config` file and select  the **Migrate packages.config to PackageReference...** option. This will add a required `<PackageReference>` to the `.csproj` project file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Mvvm">
    <Version>8.1.0</Version>
  </PackageReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

Then open the project file and set the C# language version to 8.0 or higher:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  ...
  <LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

If you then reload the project, build and run it should work.